# How do I enable an overlay to pop up on a webpage depending on the item I click?

Tags: jquery, html, css

If you go to http://www.sherwin-williams.com/painting-contractors/project-solutions/residential-repaints/facility-illustration-guides/ ,you will notice that when you click on the '+' an overlay pops up.  I was curious as to how they were getting this done, so I downloaded the source and decided to play around with it.

I was able to recreate the webpage here (http://residentialrepaint.com/repaints.php), but I noticed the overlays didn't work.  I tried digging through the jquery-ui.min.js file where I think the problem is, but the file is very large and hard to dig through.  I think maybe the file is fine, but there is some linking error.  Does anybody know how to get this working, and where the problem lies so that I can better understand how the overlays are working?

Comment: Dude, there are few error on your page, i suppose you resolve it first before we start working on the overlay issue.I was able to see this in firebug console on firefox , mostly some resources have missed out.

Comment: Do you have some example code to help narrow down what the fix might be? Can you put it inline?

Comment: @dreamweiver few errors? no lol there is a huge list of 404 errors.
opethgeek you need to inspect element on the page and fix those 404s first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a jQuery UI overlay to appear on click I would do something like this...

```
var $dialog = $('<div id="dialog" title="Dialog Title">Dialog Text</div>');

$('#buttonID').click( function() {

    $dialog.dialog({
        resizable: true,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Ok": function () {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }               
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

downloading the source is always a bad idea and requires a lot of work.

*You can use the jquery sample that @didilioo posted. But since you need 14 popups, then its gonna get messy.*

What i recommend is that you use a jquery plugin to help you with this, there are a lot of plugins that can help you bring a popup, some are free and some require some money.

What a jquery plugin does it that it contains all the code that is needed to bring up the popup. Most of these plugins also have customizability options that can help you make a popup that would fit your needs.

Check out this [free one](http://zurb.com/playground/reveal-modal-plugin), its one of the best ones out there.

Alternatively, check out this [paid one](http://www.agapastudio.com/products/speedo-popup-jquery-plugin), and its also the best one out there.

Additional Instructions on how to set up these plugin are provided in the website.

Answer (score 0):

As Digiliooo said, a JQuery Dialog is one of the two obvious ways to go.

The other is to just show an absolutely-positioned div.. which is more flexible in terms of UI design & formatting.

```
<button id='launcher' type='button' onclick='showPopup'>Show</button>
<div id='popup' style='display:hidden; position:absolute; border:#808080 2px solid;'>
    Here's the Big Popup
    <img src='big image.jpg'>
    Lots of text <p>
    Whatever formatting &amp; styling you want.
</div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    function showPopup() {
        var popup = $('#popup');
        var nextTo = $('#launcher'); 
        popup.show();
        popup.position( 
            my: "left top",
            at: "right bottom",
            offset: "-30 0",    
            of: nextTo,
            collision: "flip"
        });
    }
</script>
```

The key requirement is to call position() *after* you call show().